# I want to create an instant filter using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, filter

Problem is, I don't know either language. I'm pretty good at modifying existing scripts but I can't seem to find any that suit my needs.

I want to be able to have two drop down menus and a button. From the two dropdowns lets say you can select variable A and variable B, then when the button is pressed, I want it to show an item from a list which satisfies both A and B (preferably without a refresh or need for PHP).

Are there any existing scripts like this which I can modify or is it too much to do without knowing the language?

Thanks.

Comment: jQuery is just a library to simplify certain tasks in Javascript. It is not it's own language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this. Insted of alerts put your filtering code.

```
<body>

<script>

function onSelect(){
    var selectmenu1=document.getElementById("select1");
    var selectmenu2=document.getElementById("select2");

    alert("First value: " + selectmenu1.options[selectmenu1.selectedIndex].value);
    alert("Second value: " + selectmenu2.options[selectmenu2.selectedIndex].value);
}

</script>

<select id="select1">
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
</select>

<select id="select2">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<input type="button" onclick="onSelect();" value="Submit!"/>

</body>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm not sure how to get this to filter a list but I'll do some searching.

Comment: Please don't forget to mark the question as answered so other people that have a similar problem can find the answer.